# C++ setprecision (setting number of decimals 1-10)

Tags: c++

**EDIT** So I posted the HTML and the code that I'm using. I'm not getting any errors but it's not doing anything different with the amount of decimals?

So I have a form that the user will pick 1 through 10 to decide how many decimals will be displayed for a calculation to display "answer". I'm trying to use setprecision, please help me clean up my code

```
int decDropDown;

getvar("decDropDown",  dest4,buffer);

decDropDown = atoi(dest4); // The decimal value

if(decDropDown == 1)
{
    cout<<setprecision(decDropDown)<<answer<<endl;
}
else if(decDropDown == 2)
{
    cout<<setprecision(decDropDown)<<answer<<endl;
}
```

..and so on and so forth.

HTML

```
<p>Please select how many decimal places to show your answer :  
<select name="decDropDown">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what errors have you got?

Comment: did you include iomanip??

Comment: Why not just do `setprecision(decimalValue)`?

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: You should include a description of the error instead of making us guess.

Comment: Here is a working example of using `setprecision()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision

Comment: @Marty Huggins see my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{ 
    double whatever = 3.13;
    // using IOManip header:
    std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << std::fixed << whatever << std::endl; 
}
```

**setprecision** is part of the standard namespace, so if you don't call *use std::setprecision and std::fixed* or **using namespace std;** you will have to use *std::setprecision* and *std::fixed* instead of *setprecision* or *fixed*.

You didn't show us what your header declarations look like, so judging from what you posted you probably need to include the header file or use the scope resolution operator.

Comment: I tried swapping this portion of the code 'std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << std::fixed << whatever << std::endl;' but it didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong? I edited my main post

Comment: That wasn't meant for you to 'swap' into your project.  I was providing a 'proof of concept' of sorts.  If you run the code that I gave you, you will understand what it does.  Here at stack overflow we try to answer questions in ways that will encourage the asker to learn themselves.

Comment: @MartyHuggins it might also give you an idea as to how number types work in C++

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with that code, but you should instead use this, it will save time.

```
cout<<setprecision(decimalValue)<<answer<<endl;
```

Comment: Except without the extra double-quote on the end.